# why does my code giving not a correct sum but code seems correct

Tags: function, recursion

/*write a function to find the sum of (1 to the power d+ 2 to the power d+....+n to the power d)the sum of d (t h) power of the first n natural numbers ,where n and d are given as input*/

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<math.h>

float sum(int n ,int d);

int main(){
   int n=3,d=2;

   printf("sum=%f\n",sum(3,2));

   return 0;
}

float sum(int n ,int d){
   float sum;

   for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    sum=0;
    sum= sum+pow(i ,d);
   }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sum = 0 which you written inside the for loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float sum(int n ,int d);

int main() {
  int n=3,d=2;
  printf("sum=%f\n",sum(3,2));
  return 0;
}

float sum(int n ,int d) {
  float sum = 0;
  for (int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    // sum=0; Comment this line because it's making it zero again.
    sum= sum+pow(i ,d);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: i was also thinking that it needs to initialise first but by initialising 'sum' it is giving error (  according to mr. Gopal  result is coming right).

Comment: Yes @Clifford you are right. I missed that. I updated the code. praveen you can try now